# How to make the marker movement smooth on google maps (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have made a simple map.js file. I have to loop through all the locations and plot marker accordingly, erasing previous one and show smooth marker movement.

This is what I've tried. So far, it just puts the marker on the final location ad I know why also (because of `setTimeout()`) but I don't know how to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is just a part of the whole code.

```
var lat;
var lng;
var oldLat;
var oldLng;
var marker;
var map;
var numDeltas = 100;
var delay = 10; //milliseconds
var j = 0;
var deltaLat;
var deltaLng;

oldLat = data.data[0].lat;
oldLng = data.data[0].long;

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(oldLat, oldLng),
  map: map,
}); 

for(var i=1; i<72; i++)
{
    lat = data.data[i].lat;  //have the data
    lng = data.data[i].long;  //have the data
    transition(lat, lng);
    oldLat = lat;
    oldLng = lng;
}

function transition(lat, lng)
{
    j = 0;
    deltaLat = (Number(lat) - Number(oldLat))/numDeltas;
    deltaLng = (Number(lng) - Number(oldLng))/numDeltas;
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(oldLat, oldLng);
    moveMarker(latlng);
}

function moveMarker(latlng)
{
    marker.setPosition(latlng);
    oldLat = Number(oldLat) + deltaLat;
    oldLng = Number(oldLng) + deltaLng;
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(oldLat, oldLng);
    if(j!=numDeltas)
    {
        j++;
        setTimeout(moveMarker(latlng), delay);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't give you the whole code. Policy. This works but puts the marker on the last point. No animation.

Comment: I know. But the data (which I'm using in this) comes from a socket connection to the server.

Comment: I'm sorry. But I can't. It would be too tedious.

Comment: No. If you don't want to, you can ignore this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider the following approach:

- generate marker collection per every location
- display a marker using `marker.setVisibility(value)`

**Example**

```js
var markers = [];
function initialize() {
    
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 6,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.526964, 23.617352),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var startPos = new google.maps.LatLng(60.174039, 24.940939);
    var endPos = new google.maps.LatLng(59.337174, 18.067883);
   

    // generate fake points for route
    var pointsNo = 80;
    var latDelta = (endPos.lat() - startPos.lat()) / pointsNo;
    var lngDelta = (endPos.lng() - startPos.lng()) / pointsNo;
    var positions = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < pointsNo; i++) {
        var curLat = startPos.lat() + i * latDelta;
        var curLng = startPos.lng() + i * lngDelta;
        positions.push(new google.maps.LatLng(curLat, curLng));


        var curMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(curLat, curLng),
            visible: false
        });
        markers.push(curMarker);
    }
}




function displayMarker(markers, index, delay) {    
    if (index > 0)
        markers[index - 1].setVisible(false);
    else {
        markers[markers.length - 1].setVisible(false);
    }

    markers[index].setVisible(true);
    if (index < markers.length - 1) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            displayMarker(markers, index + 1, delay);
        }, delay);
    } else {
        displayMarker(markers, 0, delay);
    }
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
    initialize();
});


function move() {
    var delay = 40;
    displayMarker(markers, 0, delay);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input type="button" value="Move" onclick="move();"/>
<div id="map" style="width: 480px; height: 320px;"></div>
```

Comment: I don't know the final location. It gets updated in real time. Also I tried setTimeout(). It doesn't work for me. It always places the marker on the final position.

Comment: I dont see in your question any mention about final location, the example i've provided demonstrates only how to move marker

Comment: You're moving it from one point to another only. Try putting the code in a for loop. The setTimeout() messes up then. I tried my code on a 2 point system and it worked then.

Comment: Try putting the code in a for loop.. what are talking about? In the provided example **is generated a collection of 80 points** and then the corresponding marker is displayed

Comment: Ohh sorry. My bad. Will check and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
  #map_canvas {
    width: 700px;
    height: 500px;
  }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
  var marker;  // let's keep this global, so we can easily access it everywhere
  var map;

  // initialize Google Maps
  function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.8, 4.7),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.8, 4.7),
      map: map
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  // takes a marker and smoothly moves it to a new position
  function markerTransition(marker, oldPosition, newPosition, i) {
    // settings, feel free to change these
    var steps = 72;
    var timerInterval = 50;  // every step takes 50ms
    // we calculate the temporary position
    var tempPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(
      oldPosition.lat() + i * (newPosition.lat() - oldPosition.lat()) / steps,
      oldPosition.lng() + i * (newPosition.lng() - oldPosition.lng()) / steps    
    );
    marker.setPosition(tempPosition);
    if(i<steps) {
      setTimeout(function() {
          markerTransition(marker, oldPosition, newPosition, i+1);
        },
        timerInterval
      );
    }
  }
</script>
<div id="section"></div>
<p id="map_canvas" ></p>
<hr>
Zoom out so you can see start and end<br>
From Paris to Brussels.
<input value="GO" type="button" onclick="markerTransition(marker, new google.maps.LatLng(48.85818520410521,2.294554978609), new google.maps.LatLng(50.89512908591323,4.341423779726), 0);"> 
<br>
First we'll take Manhattan, then we take Berlin
<input value="GO" type="button" onclick="markerTransition(marker, new google.maps.LatLng(40.76784982139687,-73.97199574112894), new google.maps.LatLng(52.52207312527306,13.41274318099), 0);">
```

Comment: The thing is, I don't know what the final location will be. It's getting updated in realtime.

Comment: Okay, I made an edit.  As you can see, you can call the function any time (also after getting real time data)